# GridView - Dynamic Button Control Click Event Not Firing - Sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridViews on a single page, each GridView is modified in the code-behind to group using RowDataBound and within the RowDataBound I am adding a TextBox and Button for each grouping. The Button is added with a Click event. Also, each GridView is in an UpdatePanel.

In order to get around the PostBack issue with RowDataBound items and dynamic controls I have added a simple Response.Redirect to the same page. This code works BUT the Buttons stop firing the Click event about half way down the GridView list. After the half way mark the click just acts like it is initiating a PostBack instead of firing the click event, which gives same results as the problem of the RowDataBound information being stripped out.

From what I can tell, the click event is not being called. This is the code I have.

```
protected void GridViewRowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        nonPaidCLB.Visible = true;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (tmpCategoryName != drv["Num"].ToString())
            {
                string useTable = "";
                string giftDoorPrize = "";
                if (drv["Table"].Equals("N"))
                {
                    useTable = " - NOT Using Table";
                }
                if (drv["Gift"].Equals("Y"))
                {
                    giftDoorPrize = " - Providing gift or door prize";
                }
                tmpCategoryName = drv["Num"].ToString();
                Table tbl = e.Row.Parent as Table;
                if (tbl != null)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.ColumnSpan = this.GridView.Columns.Count;
                    cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                    cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#4382C0");
                    cell.Style.Add("color", "white");

                    TextBox notes2TXTBOX = new TextBox();
                    notes2TXTBOX.ID = "notes2TXTBOX";
                    notes2TXTBOX.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    notes2TXTBOX.Text = drv["Notes"].ToString();
                    notes2TXTBOX.Style.Add("width", "400px");

                    Label payInfoID2TXTBOX = new Label();
                    payInfoID2TXTBOX.ID = "payInfoID2TXTBOX";
                    payInfoID2TXTBOX.Text = drv["PayID"].ToString();
                    payInfoID2TXTBOX.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    Button saveNotes2BTN = new Button();
                    saveNotes2BTN.ID = "saveNotes2BTN";
                    saveNotes2BTN.Text = "Update";
                    saveNotes2BTN.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    saveNotes2BTN.Click += saveNotes2_OnClick;

                    string paidStr = string.Empty;
                    string invoiceReceiptStr = string.Empty;
                    decimal totalCost = 0;
                    totalCost = (Convert.ToInt16(drv["NumAtt"]) - 1) * Convert.ToDecimal(drv["FullF"]) + Convert.ToDecimal(drv["PartF"]) + Convert.ToDecimal(drv["CSPF"]);

                    if (drv["pd"].Equals("Y"))
                    {
                        paidStr = "<strong>PAID</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        invoiceReceiptStr = " <a href='resendReceipt.aspx?payRegID=" + drv["PaymentInfoID"] + "&totalCost=" + totalCost + "' style='color:white;' >RESEND RECEIPT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        paidStr = "<a href='confirmPaid.aspx?payRegID=" + drv["PayID"] + "' style='color:black;' >MARK PAID</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        invoiceReceiptStr = " <a href='resendInvoice.aspx?payRegID=" + drv["PayID"] + "&totalCost=" + totalCost + "' style='color:WHITE;' >RESEND INVOICE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                    string cspText = "";
                    if (!drv["CSPF"].ToString().Equals("0.0000"))
                    {
                        cspText = ", CSPresenter ($" + Convert.ToDecimal(drv["ConcurSesPresFee"]).ToString("#,##0.00") + ")";
                    }
                    HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
                    span.InnerHtml = "<a href='/Events/Invoice.aspx?confID=" + conferenceDDL.SelectedValue + "&payID=" + drv["PayID"] + "' target='_blank' style='color:white;' >" + tmpCategoryName + "</a>" + useTable + "" + giftDoorPrize + ",&nbsp;Sponsor Fee: $" + Convert.ToDecimal(drv["PartF"].ToString()).ToString("#,##0.00") + cspText + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + paidStr + invoiceReceiptStr + "<div style='float:right;'>Total: $" + Convert.ToDecimal(totalCost).ToString("#,##0.00") + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NOTES:&nbsp;";
                    cell.Controls.Add(span);
                    cell.Controls.Add(notes2TXTBOX);
                    cell.Controls.Add(saveNotes2BTN);
                    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, the code works for the first several items in the GridView BUT then it stops working. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add controls dynamically, and catch the event like the way you are doing.

### Step 1

You need to place all ServerControls inside the GridView's Template columns.

### Step 2

Find the ServerControl you want to manipulate inside **GridViewRowDatabound**. For example,

```
Button button = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("MyButton");
```

Then do whatever you want to the ServerControl based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response Win. I am a little confused by your response though. As I said, the code above works for half the items in a single GridView. So you are saying, I need to add each control as a column in the GridView template? And then call it in GridViewRowDatabound? If this is the case, why would it work for the previous columns and not the last half? I'm just trying to get my mind around this.

Comment: Regular server control (such as TextBox and Label) work fine. The problem is attaching click event; **saveNotes2** is created dynamically, so it is not in the **control tree**. By the time, the code reaches to `saveNotes2BTN.Click += saveNotes2_OnClick`, it is too late to fire the click event.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by moving the TextBox, Label, and Button (with the OnClick event) controls to the Template in .Net. Since all of these were moved to the front there wasn't anything to do within the GridViewRowDatabound except grouping. No luck! Just like before, the first half of each list is acting differently, it is initiating what looks like the Response.Redirect but is not posting to the DB which is what the OnClick is supposed to do. The second half is reacting the same way as before by a PostBack and no call to OnClick. The code works if I remove the grouping but this is needed.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?  I'm running into a similar issue in some legacy code.  During the course of loading the grid, the page adds rows for totals for groups of rows.  There are 5 "totals" lines and buttons in the last 5 detail rows will only trigger redirect, not button_click.